# PHP: handling a POST request sent from Perl

Tags: php, perl

I'm new to PHP and I seem to be doing something wrong. On one hand, I have a Perl script that looks like this:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $url = 'https://url/index.php';

my $response = $browser->post($url, [
        "command" => "test",
            "data" => "123"
         ]);

die "Error getting $url" unless $response->is_success;

print $response->content;
```

On the server, the index.php file looks like this:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){ 
    echo "Hello!\n";
}else {
    echo "Error\n";
}
?>
```

And... that's it. If I try to execute the Perl script, however, **it prints the whole index.php file, instead of Hello! or that other error message**. I guess it makes sense that I'm requesting a file and that's what it's printing, however I'm quite confused about what it is I'm doing wrong. I've been looking around for examples for a while but I've found nothing so far that could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem here is that the server doesn't know that it should be treating the PHP file as PHP. Instead of parsing/interpreting it it's just returning it.

Make sure that you have PHP installed on the server and then make sure that the following line is in your Apache config:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php php
```

Comment: Where is this file located in Linux (Ubuntu, to be specific)? I'm guessing I should restart the Apache server after adding in this line?

Comment: Found it at `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

Comment: You might need to install PHP5: Ubuntun Docs: [ApacheMySQLPHP](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP), [Official Ubuntu Documentation (Start)](https://help.ubuntu.com/), [Server Guide for 10.04 LTS (April 2010, codenamed Lucid Lynx)](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/index.html) -> **[PHP5 - Scripting Language](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/php5.html)**

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you don't have PHP set up on your server.

[Here's some info](http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php) on the steps required to get it up and running on Apache. Even if you have the module installed, you are likely missing some httpd.conf configuration steps.

Answer (score 1):

Can you load `https://url/index.php` in your web browser?  My first guess would be that your Webserver isn't executing PHP and is just outputting the contents of the index.php file.